# How to make a buffer stream for storing strings in memory?

Tags: java

I have following task: to make application for uploading data into FTP server using apache.commons.net.FTPClient, etc. There is method client.storeFile() which allows to upload file (it requires InputStream as 1 of method parameters). But I want to make txt file into server which should contain array of strings - array is variable of program. Should I make file, put strings into it and transfer this file into method, or there is stream which allow to store strings in memory without making file? Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) that you can use

Comment: Thank you, I can store my strings into BAOS. But how should I get InputStream from ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: with a `ByteArrayInputStream` as in `new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())`

Comment: I think you should use directly the `ByteArrayInputStream` with `String.getBytes`

Comment: 1 need 1 think also - how can I transfer string into next line? If I use files I can use writeLine(), but I don't know how can I do it for bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`StringBufferInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html), but as you have an array of Strings, you might need to concatenate all of them first, or use a [`SequenceInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) generating all the sub input streams...

I'd go for the second, combined with a lazy enumeration, if your array is large.

By the way, `StringBufferInputStream` is deprecated, so might want to use the `ByteArrayInputStream` and `String.getBytes(...)` methods instead.